# Match words using set of letters with one instance

Tags: regex

Had this problem thinking on how I should do this, I am playing some word games and I want to match words in a set of dictionary words with 5 letters I tried something like this

```
\b[clagey]{5}\b
```

it is good, but it is matching word like "eagle". The Problem is I want a single instance on each letters c,l,a,g,e,y not "eagle" with double e's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
\b(?:([clagey])(?!\S*\1)){5}\b
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeK1qZ/5)**

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - a word-boundary
- `([clagey])` - matches one of these characters - `c`, `l`, `a`, `g`, `e`, `y` and captures it in group 1
- `(?!\S*\1)` - negative lookahead too make sure that whatever is captured in group 1 is not repeated before the occurrence of next white-space
- `{5}` - to match 5 occurrences
- `\b` - a word boundary